# finding number times a value has been selected in a table with javaScript

Tags: javascript

excuse me, I new to web development and javaScript. I have json file contains information regarding books. I have function to display all books in a table that user can multiselect on.
what i want is if user selects multiple books from table, it displays how many of each category they have selected, for example "you have selected 2 Children's literature books and 1 computer book"

I very unsure how I do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[
{
    "ID": "1",
    "Name": "Computer Architecture",
    "Category": "Computers",
    "Price": "125.60"
},
{
    "ID": "2",
    "Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
    "Category": "Programming",
    "Price": "56.00"
},
{
    "ID": "3",
    "Name": "Popular Science",
    "Category": "Science",
    "Price": "210.40"
},
{
    "ID": "4",
    "Name": "Harry Potter",
    "Category": "Children's literature",
    "Price": "210.40"
},
{
    "ID": "3",
    "Name": "Popular Science",
    "Category": "Children's literature",
    "Price": "210.40"
}
```

]

my table function:

```
function loadAllBooks() {

    $.getJSON('books.json', function (jsonData) {
        jsonArray = jsonData;

        var data = jsonArray;
        $(".allBookTable").html('<thead><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Category</th><th>Price</th></thead><tbody class="filterAllTableBody"></tbody>');

        var containers = document.getElementsByClassName("filterAllTableBody");
        for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {

                var allTableRow = document.createElement("tr");
                var dataId = "allBooks" + j;
                allTableRow.setAttribute("data-id", dataId);
                allTableRow.className = "allBooks";

                allTableRow.innerHTML = '<td>' + (j + 1) + '</td> <td>' + data[j].Name + '</td> <td data-id="' + dataId + '">' + data[j].Category + '</td> <td>' + data[j].Price + '</td>';
                containers[i].appendChild(allTableRow);
            }
        }

    
    });
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your code segment that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this yourself, and then describe at what point in your code you aren't getting the results you expect, along with an explanation of what you expect to happen.  If you are just stuck and need someone to code this for you, perhaps consider hiring someone to either tutor you or to code it for you.

Comment: without knowing how the selected data is formatted nobody could possible give you the right answer. Your code doesn't have anything that can be selected by the user.

Comment: Please rethink and reframe your question, and ask the exact doubt/query where you are stucked. If you don't know what to do, rephrase your question to ask for guidance on the overall approach. Help the community to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap td contents in a label with a data-category attribute. Associate the label with checkbox using the for= attribute. Any click will check/uncheck (hidden?) checkbox, but you could style it how you choose. Add eventListener to form labels and re-tally status on click or on change.